# What happens when you install software?

Tags: windows, installation

I'm surprised that I couldn't find any other question answering this. (Please comment a link if you can find one!)
So, the question I'm asking is, in general, what list of things typically occur when you install a program on a Windows PC, like when you run a .exe or .msi file and go through a wizard, causing a program to be (for lack of better term) "registered" on the machine. I'm talking about things like what files or directories are usually created, what changes are made to the registry or added to the PATH, etc.

Comment: What happens is defined by the installer script

Comment: It sounds like you already have an idea that, files and directories are created and registry changes are made. What specifically happens depends on the installer and the requirements of the software. There is no "standard" thing that happens. Some programs don't use the registry at all. Some programs are portable and don't need to be installed.  A good question, but I think you already know the answer.

Comment: I think the best answer is a combination of Ramhounds and Appleoddity comments. What happens when you build a house. Yes, hammer and nails, plaster and paint. However, the decision to include the swimming pool or not, to have solar panels or not etc depends on that certain house (as it does with that installer). Sadly, although a clear question, I feel this is off topic :( I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) stated, this process will vary depending on the installer. If you want a *complete* list of what is physically added to, and subsequentially changed on the machine in question, you can use the following programs to capture snapshots of what an installer does:

[Cameyo client](http://www.cameyo.com/) (Freeware/Pricing varys)

[VMware ThinApp](https://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp.html) (Pricing varys)

[TurboStudio](https://turbo.net/studio) (Pricing varys)

*TurboStudio is by far the best of these overall in my opinion.*

These programs can be used to take a snapshot of the host machines current state before installing the desired program, then scan it afterwards to capture the differences and bundle them into a [virtual application](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_application).

I personally started using these *strictly* for making portable programs, but gradually began dissecting my projects to learn about how the programs in question worked.

Another alternative is to use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (Freeware), but it will not be as accurate at determining each individual function or change a program brings after it's installation. This is due to the fact that not every aspect or files of a given program are accessed, read, or written upon it's execution.

Things to keep in mind are that some programs are extremly complex, and utilize the [Windows registry](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjsvqPUgbjVAhVE12MKHXA_CsYQFggTMAI&usg=AFQjCNGfslZs-dcZNRi7vH7MUXeUCzoMRw), have [runtime dependencies](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiBlcqEgrjVAhUX1GMKHVT7DtkQFggRMAI&usg=AFQjCNGRB0Y3CscfDJpUWCt2gU08XprJrA), and/or have a battery of files and [associations](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_association&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiy45WggrjVAhUG9WMKHaF4As8QFggVMAM&usg=AFQjCNHZc5ejoux4V1gyTAnKIFmSKchhhA). On the other side, some programs are simple, small, and may not utilize things such as the registry.